Pytube RegexMatchError(caller="map_functions", pattern="multiple") map_functions: could not find match for multiple
I was recently downloading a list of Youtube URLs...all was working until today where I started receiving this error
Traceback (most recent call last): 

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pytube/main.py", line 181, in fmt_streamsextract.apply_signature(stream_manifest, self.vid_info, self.js) 

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pytube/extract.py", line 409, in apply_signaturecipher = Cipher(js=js) 

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pytube/cipher.py", line 37, in initself.transform_map = get_transform_map(js, var)

 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pytube/cipher.py", line 250, in get_transform_mapfn = map_functions(function) 

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pytube/cipher.py", line 698, in map_functionsraise RegexMatchError(caller="map_functions", pattern="multiple") 

pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: map_functions: could not find match for multiple

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):File "/var/www/html/download_youtube_urls.py", line 9, in <module>stream = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pytube/main.py", line 296, in streamsreturn StreamQuery(self.fmt_streams)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pytube/main.py", line 188, in fmt_streamsextract.apply_signature(stream_manifest, self.vid_info, self.js)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pytube/extract.py", line 409, in apply_signaturecipher = Cipher(js=js)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pytube/cipher.py", line 37, in initself.transform_map = get_transform_map(js, var)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pytube/cipher.py", line 250, in get_transform_mapfn = map_functions(function)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pytube/cipher.py", line 698, in map_functionsraise RegexMatchError(caller="map_functions", pattern="multiple")

pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: map_functions: could not find match for multiple

Everywhere I searched, I'm only finding the get_throttle_function error, but this seems to be a new issue. I attempted to run the script from another IP address, just to make sure it had nothing to do with my host machine, and I got the same error from the other host machine as well.
I've ran python3 -m pip install --upgrade pytube multiple times to verify I have the most current package, no luck.
Here is an example of my code:
#!/bin/python3

import pytube

f = open('urls.txt', 'r')
url = f.readlines()
for i in url:
        yt = pytube.YouTube(i)
        stream = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
        stream.download("/var/www/html/tmp")
f.close()

Have anyone ran into this issue? If not, can I please get some help or direction on what is going on?

I had to change line 195 of the "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pytube/cipher.py" file from
pattern = r"%s=function\(\w\){[a-z=\.\(\"\)]*;(.*);(?:.+)}" % name

To
pattern = r"%s=function\(\w\){[a-z=\.\(\"\)]*;((\w+\.\w+\([\w\"\'\[\]\(\)\.\,\s]*\);)+)(?:.+)}" % name

And also line 264 to
r'a\.[a-zA-Z]\s*&&\s*\([a-z]\s*=\s*a\.get\("n"\)\)\s*&&.*?\|\|\s*([a-z]+)',
r'\([a-z]\s*=\s*([a-zA-Z0-9$]+)(\[\d+\])?\([a-z]\)',
r'\([a-z]\s*=\s*([a-zA-Z0-9$]+)(\[\d+\])\([a-z]\)',

So far, these changes seem to have worked, although I understand the Pytube is not stable, so I may look to use other modules to download Youtube videos.

Youtube is making changes to its algorithm, if you want to download videos or audios you should use Jdownloader2 or here's the solution https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/2008

Awesome man, thanks much for the link to the correct forum
